# two TLDs in one URL

Tags: dns

What are the names for the domains in a single URL, such as in the following hypothetical examples?

http://example.com/google.com/?q=http://example.net&#id=http://example.org&

http://google.com.example.com/file.example.com#666

The second example is kindred to what is found in phishing scams and would be widely misunderstood by laity. Browsers know the difference between one domain and the others; I haven't tested but I haven't seen browsers get it wrong with safe URLs. One domain is the one for which the DNS servers look up the IP in order to send the URL to the server hosting it; the other domains are ignored by DNS for purposes of routing to the proper IP address. That might define the difference but it's not a convenient naming scheme.

Comment: Both of these examples are in the example.com domain. What naming scheme is inconvenient exactly? It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I'm asking for two abstract terms, one term for the domain that's used by DNS to identify the IP address and another term for any domains that are not used by DNS, even though all of the domains appear in one URL. It doesn't matter that the second-level domain in every subexample is "example"; it could have been anything, such as "state". The naming scheme that's inconvenient is the 25-word description or the 16-word description if either is used as a name. I assume there's already a name for the domain or domain-like string found in a URL, but I don't know where to find such a name.

Comment: “I assume there's already a name for the domain or domain-like string found in a URL” – There isn’t. That’s only natural, because there’s no fixed meaning. It could mean different things to different services/applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL's are split up into several parts. Assuming this syntax:

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

In addition to that, I usually split up the host in a domain and sub-domain, though I'm not sure if this is any official naming scheme.

With that, you can split up your examples in the following segments:

---

**`http://example.com/google.com/?q=http://example.net&#id=http://example.org&`**

- Scheme: `http`
- Host: `example.com.`
- Domain: `example.com.`
- Path: `google.com`
- Query: `q=http://example.net&`
- Fragment: `id=http://example.org&`

---

**`http://google.com.example.com/file.example.com#666`**

- Scheme: `http`
- Host: `google.com.example.com.`
- Domain: `example.com.`
- sub-domain: `google.com`
- Path: `file.example.com`
- Fragment: `666`

---

For DNS, only the host is used. You then communicate your path, and query to the server. Your browser takes care of the fragment by scrolling you to the right page or displaying or hiding content.

In the examples above, mind the dot after some of the domains. This means that they are the end of the domain, or the TLD (Top Level Domain). Sub-domains don't have this because they aren't a full reference. You can see this in DNS records too:

```
demo.example.com.   3600    IN      A               12.34.56.78
localhost           3600    IN      A               127.0.0.1
www                 3600    IN      CNAME           demo.example.com.
ftp                 3600    IN      A               12.34.56.78
```

These DNS records would result in the following hosts:

- demo.example.com, resolving to 12.34.56.78
- localhost.example.com, resolving to 127.0.0.1
- www.example.com, resolving to demo.example.com, which resolves to 12.34.56.78
- ftp.example.com, resolving to 12.34.56.78

Comment: Okay, it looks like one is a "host domain" (used for DNS), and other domains in a URL (like a domain in a query string) are nonhost domains. If I got it wrong, please indicate; in either case, thank you.

Comment: @nick It's not technically a host domain but just a host. I think of them just as the host and path, but they just happen to look like domains.